# Sort dict by second value in tuple and return dict

Tags: sorting, python-3.x, dictionary, defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict,OrderedDict
tt=defaultdict (list)

tt={'abcd':(23,77),'ddef':(55,22)}

c=OrderedDict (sorted (tt.items (),key=lambda t: t[1][1]))

print (c)
d=list ((k,v) for k,v in c.items())

print (d)
```

This sorts correctly for c.
List makes the dict from the OrderedDict

d gets  {'ddef':(55,22),'abcd':(23,77)}

Comment: Why do you need your dict in a specific order? There are a few legitimate use cases, but usually, either a list is better, or order isn't actually necessary. (There's a fundamental tradeoff between data structures that choose where their elements go and data structures where you choose where their elements go. Dicts choose where their elements go, which makes key lookup fast but requires extra overhead to maintain a sense of ordering.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the code. Works fine now.
I need to display top (n) keys in a sorted order by the second element of the tuple.
Dict seems to be the best route, there are only ever 50 items in the list,I need the top ten in order.